# Tcl set command

Tags: command, set, tcl

Quick question... I'm trying the following:

```
set changedir "cd $JSDIR/"

eval $changedir
```

..Where $JSDIR is defined already. Running this script gives the error: "set: Variable name must begin with a letter."

What's the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait... I was able to just do 'cd $JSDIR' directly, i.e. I didn't need eval. Do I ever need eval in Tcl?

Comment: Do you ever need eval? Very, very rarely. As in, you can go years without needing to use eval. Some day you might be trying something advanced and discover eval s ne rigjt tool for tne job and you'll be glad it's there. Since you are just now learning Tcl, just pretend it isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error message generated by Tcl, because Tcl's variables most definitely do *not* need to begin with a letter. OK, it tends to be convenient to keep them alphanumeric because the `$var` shorthand syntax is more restrictive than the general space of variable names, but the `set var` form can handle virtually anything.

I'm guessing that script is being evaluated by something that isn't Tcl, perhaps bash?

Comment: By “virtually anything”, I mean it is only necessary to be careful with namespace separators (`foo::bar`) and array references (`foo(bar)`). I'd also advise avoid using anything you can't type; while Tcl would work with it fine, you'd find it very annoying!

Comment: I'm calling within linux, "source <myscript>" which I thought interprets it as Tcl

Comment: @youngMoney: no, `source` from the prompt treats the code as a bash script.

Comment: @YoungMoney http://wiki.tcl.tk/812 tclsh or wish need to get involved at some point somehow

Answer (score 0):

Try to set changedir `cd ${JSDIR/}` instead

Answer (score -1):

This message can appear when in fact the variable name is entirely correct, and the real problem is that the variable value needs to be quoted. Try instead of: set changedir "cd $JSDIR//"

Comment: No, that error cannot appear, because Tcl has no such restriction on variable names. No matter how you quote it, you won't get that error.